# I cannot understand how to use this code in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

It regards user imput, so like I was commissioned to do a prompt but I've never done this so like this is what i found online

```
playerChoice = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author), timeout=30)
```

I get some of it, but I don't get the 'message' part and the 'check = check'.

Here's my full code

```py
@client.command()
async def event(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Prompt will continue in DMs.")
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Event Prompt", description="Please specify the type of event.")
    embed.set_footer("Prompt will expire in ## seconds")
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
    eventType = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author), timeout=30) # I want it to send the event type.
    await ctx.send(eventType)
```

I'd like an explaination and a possible way to improve that and make it work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$greet'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Say hello!')

        def check(m):
            return m.content == 'hello' and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await channel.send('Hello {.author}!'.format(msg))
```

> ```
> await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
> ```

`message` refers to the event. You could have also do it for the event `reaction_add`, `voice_state_update`, etc.
So this means you are waiting for a message. The `check` defines what you are waiting for exactly. It is a method and returns a `True` or `False`.

In my case I am waiting for a `message` event which is posted in the same `channel` and has the message content `"hello"`.

If you didn't have such check it would pick up a `message` that might have been send by a different author, in a different channel, in a different guild.

Comment: if i want to convert that in a command, how would i do that? would i just replace message with ctx?